# SQL query REGEX_SUBTR IP Range

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have an application GUI that allows you to enter an IP range and performs a query to pull records that only have clientIP's that fall within that range. I have been working on automating this functionality and have most of it working but I am having difficulty understanding the regex_subst syntax. This is the part of the query I pulled from Oracle sessions, that I would like to either hard code with IP's or insert the values via variables.

```
AND REGEXP_LIKE(m.CLIENTIP, '^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$') 
AND CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(m.CLIENTIP,'[0-9]{1,3}',1, 4) AS NUMBER) BETWEEN :22  AND :23 AND CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(m.CLIENTIP,'[0-9]{1,3}',1, 3) AS NUMBER) BETWEEN :24  AND :25  
AND CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(m.CLIENTIP,'[0-9]{1,3}',1, 2) AS NUMBER) BETWEEN :26  AND :27  AND CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(m.CLIENTIP,'[0-9]{1,3}',1) AS NUMBER) BETWEEN :28  AND :29)
```

if I wanted to find records between 10.35.0.0 -> 10.35.255.255 , where would these values plug into the above syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303)(m.CLIENTIP,'[0-9]{1,3}',1, 2) means, extract a group of 1-3 numbers, starting the search from position 1 and matching 2nd occurrence of the group.

So, if your m.CLIENTIP is 10.35.23.12,

- `REGEXP_SUBSTR(m.CLIENTIP,'[0-9]{1,3}',1, 4)` will extract 12
- `REGEXP_SUBSTR(m.CLIENTIP,'[0-9]{1,3}',1, 3)` will extract 23
- `REGEXP_SUBSTR(m.CLIENTIP,'[0-9]{1,3}',1, 2)` will extract 35
- `REGEXP_SUBSTR(m.CLIENTIP,'[0-9]{1,3}',1)` will extract 10 ( here the fourth parameter is omitted and is considered as 1 by default)

To answer your query,

- :22  should be 0
- :23  should be 255
- :24  should be 0
- :25  should be 255
- :26  should be 35
- :27  should be 35
- :28  should be 10
- :29  should be 10

Comment: Thank you so very much for the help, the explanation helped a ton and works exactly as I need it. My queries are pulling the same metrics as the app gui now. Thanks again.